# Wholesale store - if statement not working

Tags: if-statement, shopify, liquid

I'm setting up a wholesale store but having multiple usergroups. The first usergroup `rdg000141` works fine but after the `elsif` part, the code stops working.

```
{% if template contains 'rdg000141' or template contains 'wholesale' %}
    {% if customer.tags contains 'rdg000141' and template contains 'rdg000141' %}
        {{ content_for_layout }}
    {% else %}
        {% include 'wholesale-note' %}
    {% elsif customer.tags contains 'wholesale' and template contains 'wholesale' %}
        {{ content_for_layout }}
    {% else %}
        {% include 'rdg000141-note' %}
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {{ content_for_layout }}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Cheers

Comment: How is it not working? Please, be more specific.

Comment: I fixed the indentation for you - and now you can see what's wrong. You have `else` before `elsif` which is invalid. You can only have one `else` in an `if` block, and it must be the last branch.

Comment: This is the revised version that a liquid coder has submitted to me but is still not working correctly, the problem i'm currently having is that one usergroup will work fine for example wholesale group is protected from the public and working correctly, so people without the usergroup tag or the public cannot view the product pages, but when you switch over to the rdg group the products are blocked even if the user has the tag.

Comment: {% if template contains 'rdg000141' %}
      {% if customer.tags contains 'rdg000141' %}
            {{ content_for_layout }}
      {% else %}
            {% include 'wholesale-note' %}
      {% endif %}
{% elsif template contains 'wholesale' %}
      {% if customer.tags contains 'wholesale' %}
            {{ content_for_layout }}
      {% else %}
            {% include 'wholesale-note' %}
      {% endif %}
{% else %}
      {{ content_for_layout }}
{% endif %}

Comment: @juzraai i've tried you code but all i get notified with is the wholesale-note ? i'm not to sure why this appears

Comment: Okay so 
{% if template contains 'rdg000141' %}
      {% if customer.tags contains 'rdg000141' %}
            {{ content_for_layout }}
      {% else %}
            {% include 'wholesale-note' %}
      {% endif %}
{% elsif template contains 'wholesale' %}
      {% if customer.tags contains 'wholesale' %}
            {{ content_for_layout }}
      {% else %}
            {% include 'wholesale-note' %}
      {% endif %}
{% else %}
      {{ content_for_layout }}
{% endif %}
{% endif %} 

This has fixed it now